# IVT of convolution integral

Tags: calculus, analysis

Trying to prove that for any $x>0$ and smooth function $g(t)$ on $[0,x]$, there exists some $0<y<x$ such that $\int_0^x (x-t)^n g(t)dt = x(x-y)^ng(y)$

Can this be done directly ( without using the IVT for integrals ) ?

Answer (score 1):

Written under the form $$\dfrac{1}{x}\int_0^x f_x(t)dt = f_x(y)$$

where $ f_x(t):=(x-t)^n g(t)$, do you recognize the Mean Value Theorem ?

(the fact that it is a convolution integral doesn't play a rôle).

Comment: tried to use MVT, with $F(x)=\int_0^x g(x,t)dt$ to no avail, was hoping not to just reference the IVT for integrals but give a direct proof

Comment: Incorrectly, i tried $\dfrac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}= F'(y)$ for some $y$, but $F'(y) \ne  (x-y)^ng(y)$ in this case, right?

Comment: @K4000 You can write down this but the "y" value you find in this way is not in general the same "y" as in my solution...

Comment: defining $h(z)=(x-z)^ng(z)$ then if $m\le (x-t)^ng(t)\le M$ for all $0\le t\le x$, we must have  $m=h(z_1)$ and $M=h(z_2)$ for some $z_1,z_2\in [0,x]$

$h(z_1)x\le \int_0^x h(t)dt \le h(z_2)x$


so $h(z_1)\le \dfrac{1}{x} \int_0^x  (x-t)^ng(t)dt \le h(z_2)$

Therefore there exists some $y$ between $z_1$ and $z_2$ such that $h(y)= \dfrac{1}{x} \int_0^x  (x-t)^ng(t)dt$

Comment: There are different MVT; the one I have used expresses the intuitive property of a mean,or, also on the side of intuition, if we write it (always in the context that for a given $x$ there exists $y$ such that...) under the form $\int_0^x f_x(t)dt =x \times f_x(y)$, it expresses that the area under a curve can be "flattened" in such a way that it is the area of a rectangle with base length $x$ and a certain height that is a $f_x(y)$ for a certain $y$...

Comment: I agree with the rigorous proof you just gave.